# How do I use StAX instead of XPP for XStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to use a fast pull parser for XStream's reading, but the default pull parser from Java 6. (Not DOM!) What do I have to do?

Answer (score 3):

Pass the appropriate driver to the XStream constructor:

```
XStream xs = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
String xml = xs.toXML(someObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to reduce the dependencies to jar files but from my oservation the `XppDriver` performs better than the `StaxDriver`. So if you need higher parsing speed just go with the default. Maybe others made different observations.

Answer (score 0):

xpp driver was last updated in 2004

I would rather use stax or dom driver